# neo4j: bicycle navigation calculating altitude difference

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am trying to find the shortest path between two nodes. The relationships have a property "length_km" which I can use as a weight property. The relationship also has a property "altitude_difference" between the two nodes it connects: (altitude-EndNode minus altitude-StartNode). Now the tricky part:

I want to accumulate all the alltitude-differences the cylcist has to climb. In case the cyclist is going downhill the altitude_difference should not be accumulated.

**I could easily implement this by having two relationships between two nodes**: The relationship would always have the altitude_difference set correctly respective its direction. At query-time I would only traverse the graph according to direction of the relationships and could accumulate the given altitude_differences.

But since I have read that having two "reciprocal" relationships between two nodes is an anti-pattern because the information is already included in just one relationship, I am wondering if there is a way of respecting the direction of the relationship at query-time.

**Now the question again in plain text: Do I need two relationships between every two nodes, or can I get a handle on the traversed direction of a relationship when searching shortest paths? Basically I would use the traversed direction (against or with the direction of the relation) as a mulitplier (1 or 0) in the aggregate function**

Comment: I think it's not an anti-pattern if you can easily implement your queries with two relationships.

Comment: I am having a hard time understanding your data model. Can you show us an example of how you would `CREATE` 2 end nodes and the 2 relationships between them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In you case it's not anti-pattern, because your model is directed graph. In other words, direction of the relationships is important. Neo4j doesn't support bidirectional relationship. You need to create relationship as incoming and second outcoming.

**Model**

```
CREATE (mountain1:Mountain {name: "Mount Whitney", altitude: 4421})
CREATE (mountain2:Mountain {name: "Mount Williamson", altitude: 4382})
CREATE (mountain1)-[:DESCENT {length_km: 20, altitude_difference: 39}]->(mountain2)
CREATE (mountain2)-[:ASCEND {length_km: 20, altitude_difference: 39}]->(mountain1)
```

You have few options how to deal with your problem

- You can have 'altitude_difference' on the relationship, but when you change altitude of the peak you also need to update two relationships.
- Calculate 'altitude_difference' as difference between altitudes. You should be able to do that in Cypher or in the application.